# SP Online : The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am getting this error only on pages library content types. If I add same taxonomy columns in list and try to save data then its working fine but when I am adding same taxonomy column in pages library, SP giving me error (**The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields**) while saving data.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This template was created using PnP site provisioning. I have reapplied site provisioning on same template and its started working.